# Fetching only required/desired fields from the class records in Parse Database

Tags: rest, parse-platform, parse-server

I have the below code in python which is used to fetch only a single field `A_Loc_Topic` from the `Locations` class records. This is the solution that I found in the parse documents.

```
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('MYPARSESERVERAPI', 443)
params = urllib.urlencode({"keys":"A_Loc_Topic"})
connection.connect()
connection.request('GET', '/classes/Locations?%s' % params, '', {
   "X-Parse-Application-Id": "APPID",
   "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "RESTAPIKEY"
 })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
```

But, this is not working. **Rather it is returning all the fields from** `Locations`
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is it returning all the data with the fields, or is it just returning the data for the field you selected, and undefined for the rest? Nothing looks wrong looking at the example at this url http://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#queries

Right above "Queries on Array Values".

Comment: Its returning all the data with fields irrespective of the key I have given @JakeT. In the official docs, it is given the same way. But when I tried in python the result is not as expected.

Comment: I notice you're missing the `/1/` from the url, though that may be due to the difference between hosted Parse.com and Parse-server... Other than trying with that /1/ in the url, my only final suggestion would be changing `'/classes/Locations?%s' % params` to `'/classes/Locations?keys=A_Loc_Topic`, which should be what the urlencode converts to. It's possible that's not converting properly.  Your current code is creating a variable params, which is a string, that should be `keys=A_Loc_Topic`, and passing that as a URL parameter. Print `params` to confirm this. You're substituding params for %s

Comment: I'm using a third party parse database `(back4app.com)` in which the url doesn't contains `/1/`. So here I should try by removing `/1/` unlike parse server. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try and revert back @JakeT.

Comment: I'm not sure the database you are using should matter when you interact with parse-server. The server layer is what interacts with your database, and your app interacts with the server.

Comment: @JakeT., When I have written with  `/1/`, I couldn't get the result. The `back4app` people asked me to remove `/1/` and try. I did the same and that's working.

Comment: The /1/ is something hosted Parse.com used, which the guides you used date back to. Whatever you need to include in your URL depends entirely on your server configuration. Most of the parse-server examples use `/api/`, though it's entirely configurable. You could do `/poop/` if you really wanted to, though I wouldn't advise it. Did trying to hard code the expected results of the encoded url work? My suggestion was based on not knowing exactly how urlencode handles the underscores and differences in case.